"No candidates found to host preview" error when iOS Widget Extension file is not in the main project
I'm trying to export an iOS Widget Extension as a CocoaPods library. Since adding a widget extension requires a target, I should create the target manually in the host project, then transfer the widget files to the repository. Therefore, the library will just vend raw files and not act as an extension.
First question: Am I right? Is there a way to save the whole extension in the repository?
Now the Podfile is:
target 'Example' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  # I need to create a `MyWidget` widget first
  target 'MyWidgetExtension' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    
    pod 'WidgetIOSSDK', :path => '../'
  end
end

In the widget entry point (MyWidgetBundle.swift), I use the widget from the library:
import WidgetIOSSDK

@main
struct MyWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        MyWidget2()
    }
}

Build and run, the widget appears on the desktop. Then here is question 2:

I can't preview the SwiftUI if the file is not in the host project. (picture 1 below)
Even if in the host project I create a blank SwiftUI file and in the preview section I use the view from the pod library, it doesn't work either.(picture 2 below)


Is there a way to preview in other location?

error: No candidates found to host preview

error: MyWidgetExtension may have crashed

